# unique_ptr: How to safely share raw pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I am making an class which is managed by a `unique_ptr`, but for various reasons I need to give implementations access to a raw pointer to the object. However I want to ensure that users don't inadvertently delete the underlying object. I have come up with the following example code:
(It is part of a tree structure, and I need to be able to look at members of tree nodes without actually detaching them. `shared_ptr` seems like overkill in this situation.)

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class unOnly
{
    ~unOnly() {}
public:
    unOnly() {}
    friend class default_delete<unOnly>;
};

int main()
{
    unique_ptr<unOnly> ptr(new unOnly());
}
```

This compiles for me in gcc 4.4.5. However, can I be sure that in all implementations `default_delete` is what actually `delete`s the object, as opposed to some private implementation class? Should I write my own deleter to be sure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not

```
class unOnly
{
    unOnly() {}
    ~unOnly() {}
    struct deleter { void operator()(unOnly* x) { delete x; }};

public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<unOnly, deleter> handle;

    static handle create() { return handle(new unOnly); }
};

auto x = unOnly::create();
```

? Or even

```
class unOnly
{
    ~unOnly() {}
    struct deleter { void operator()(unOnly* x) { delete x; }};

public:
    unOnly() {}
    typedef std::unique_ptr<unOnly, deleter> handle;
};

unOnly::handle x(new unOnly);
```

(I prefer the former, but the latter is perhaps more in the spirit of what you're asking for)

Comment: I like the first solution; I originally wanted give it a private constructor, but `unique_ptr` doesn't construct the objects it owns.

Comment: Although you've provided two alternatives that are portable, you haven't really answer the question, which asked whether the *given* code is portable.

Comment: @RobKennedy: Praetorian answered this already with a standard quote, and as you can see it is negative. The OP wants to achieve something, we're here to help.

Answer (score 1):

The point of `unique_ptr` (besides having an object which owns it's pointer) is that you can pass it a custom deleter, so it makes sense just to write one instead of doing something else, which seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Yeah, but doing that means all the users of this class need to instantiate it as `unique_ptr<unOnly> ptr(new unOnly(), custom_deleter);`. Or he has to resort to making a factory function to dispense instances of `unOnly`.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the standard:

> **20.7.1** Class template unique_ptr
>
> *6*. [...]
>
> ```
>   template<class T, class D = default_delete<T>> class unique_ptr;
> ```
>
> **20.7.1.1.1**
>
> *1* The class template default_delete serves as the default deleter (destruction policy) for the class template unique_ptr.

So, it seems implementations of `unique_ptr` are required to use `default_delete` as the default deleter.

**EDIT:**
But this doesn't mean your approach is foolproof, see @RMartinhoFernandes' comment below.

Comment: But you can have `void default_delete<T>::operator()(T* t) { some_internal_implementation_class::do_the_deleting(t); }` and friending won't help you there.